# Возникает ошибка TemplateDoesNotExist в django python

Tags: python, django, исключения, обработка-ошибок

При попытке перехода по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/1` возникает ошибка:

```
   TemplateDoesNotExist at /news/1
database/articles_detail.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/1
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
database/articles_detail.html
Exception Location: D:\User\Python\web-app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Python Executable:  D:\User\Python\web-app\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\User\\GitHub\\Django_Lessons\\web-app\\web',
 'C:\\Users\\OurCh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OurCh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OurCh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OurCh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'D:\\User\\Python\\web-app\\venv',
 'D:\\User\\Python\\web-app\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 09 Apr 2021 09:21:27 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\User\GitHub\Django_Lessons\web-app\web\main\templates\database\articles_detail.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\User\GitHub\Django_Lessons\web-app\web\database\templates\database\articles_detail.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\User\Python\web-app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\database\articles_detail.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\User\Python\web-app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\database\articles_detail.html (Source does not exist)
```

файл urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.news_home, name='news_home'),
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news-detail'),
]
```

класс `NewsDetailView` в файле views.py:

```
class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
model = Articles
templates_name = 'database/details_views.html'
context_object_name = 'article'
```

файл `details_views.html`:

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}
Новости на сайте
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
        <p>{{ article.full_text }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `articles_detail.html` существует?

Comment: @Jack_oS, всё оказалось куда проще, чем я думал, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Такого шаблона нет или вы указали не правильную директорию файла